# How to make beautiful soup grab only what is between a set of "[:" ":]" in a web page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Good afternoon! How do I make Beautifulsoup grab only what is between multiple sets of "[:" and ":]" So far I have got the entire page in my soup, but it does not have tags, sadly.

[What it looks like so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RS1o2.png)

I have tried a couple of things so far:

- `soup.findAll(text="[")`
- `keys = soup.find("span", attrs = {"class": "objectBox objectBox-string"})`

  ```
  import bs4 as bs
  import urllib.request

  source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys").read()
  soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

  # ---------------------------------------------

  #  prior script that I was playing with trying to tackle this issue

  import requests
  import urllib.request
  import time
  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

  # Set URL to scrape new certs from
  newcerts = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys"

  # Connect to the URL
  response = requests.get(newcerts)

  # Parse HTML and save to BeautifulSoup Object
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

  keys = soup.find("span", attrs = {"class": "objectBox objectBox-string"})
  ```

End goal is to retrieve the public PKI keys from Azure's website at https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys

Comment: parse data from the "pre" tag.
As you can see it is a JSON or python dict format.
It is structured as: in dict you have "keys" and its value is a list of 3 other dicts being the information you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant to grab. Try the script below:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys'

res = requests.get(url)
jsonobject = json.loads(res.content)
for item in jsonobject['keys']:
    print(item['x5c'])
```